# How to get all the items of a select box in a textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Select Box with some options ... a text box and a button ... now I want if I press the button all the values of the Select Box will get copy to the text box having `,` or `;` or any **separator** in between ....

I want to do it through **javascript** ... How can I do It ???

My code is somewhat like :-

```
<select name= "selectScript" >
<option selected= "selected" value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
<option value= "VBscript">VBscript</option>
<option value= "VBscript">Java</option>
<option value= "Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type= "text" name="txtScript" >

<input type= "button" />
```

Comment: Where *exactly* are you stuck? Please post what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML :**

```
<select id="selectScript" name= "selectScript" >
    <option selected= "selected" value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
    <option value= "VBscript">VBscript</option>
    <option value= "VBscript">Java</option>
    <option value= "Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type= "text" id="txtScript" name="txtScript" >
<input type= "button" onclick="addToArray();" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
<script>
    function addToArray() {
        var selectobject=document.getElementById("selectScript");
        for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++)
            document.getElementById("txtScript").value += 
            selectobject.options[i].value + ((i!=selectobject.length-1) ? ", " : "");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using pure javascript. You will need to add IDs to your elements.

```
var options = document.getElementById('id of your select').options;

var result = "";

for(var i;i<options.length;i++) {
  result += options[i].value + ";";
}

document.getElementById('id of your text input').value = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jquery,

```
var selections = '';
$("select option:selected").each(function() {
      selections += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
});
$("input[type='text']).val(selections);
```

Of course, you'll still need to define what triggers the action.

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* And with >3000 rep, you should know better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. * Note that I have added "id" attributes to all parent elements

```
<select name= "selectScript" id="selectbox">  
<option selected= "selected" value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
<option value= "VBscript">VBscript</option>
<option value= "VBscript">Java</option>
<option value= "Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type= "text" name="txtScript" id="textbox">

<input type= "button" id="button"/>

<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
$("#selectbox").each(function(){
   $("#textbox").append($(this).text()+";");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: OP is asking for a javascript solution.

Comment: JQuery is a JavaScript Library I guess... I feel there's no need to hard code it in JavaScript when there are such advanced tools already.

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*